# Shorthand for picking object properties - combine ES6 `Object Deconstruction` with `Object Property Value` shorthand

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Following code outputs `{name: "Bob", surname: "Smith"}` and it works fine. I want to know can I make it shorter.

```
((person = { name: 'Bob', surname: 'Smith', age: 22, }) => {
    const {
        name, // (a) create variable from deconstructing
        surname,
    } = person;

    return {
        name, // (b) reuse variable as new object parameter name (and value)
        surname
    }
})();
```

Can I somehow merge object deconstruction to variables `(a)` with returning a new object with Object Property Value shorthand `(b)`?

I use here shorthand but then its purpose is defeated by the need to manually re-use parameters. I want to mention the `name` or `surname` word in my function once not twice...

Answer (score 2):

Destructure `person` in the function's declaration:

```js
const result = (({ name, surname } = { name: 'Bob', surname: 'Smith', age: 22, }) => ({
  name, // (b) reuse variable as new object parameter name (and value)
  surname
}))();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not mention it at all

```
((person = { name: 'Bob', surname: 'Smith', age: 22, }) => {
    const {age,...ans} = person;
   return ans
})()
```

Comment: What is that magic? Explain please: what is the `ans` keyword?

Seems wrong, if I have more parameters that I want to get rid off it returns to much: 

`((person = { me: false, name: 'Bob', surname: 'Smith', age: 22, }) => {
    const {age,...ans} = person;
   return ans
})()
`

`>> {me: false, name: "Bob", surname: "Smith"}` where `me` was not expected

Comment: Just add me after age. Ans is just a variable name. You can call it whatever you want